# Removing elements from the DOM by their ID, not Index

Tags: javascript

I am making a generic todolist, the problem with my todolist is that it removes elements based on their INDEX while it takes their ID to get a position to delete
(example: let's say I add 6 items in my todolist, they all have an id from 1 to 6, if I remove 3 and 4, and then I try to remove 6, it won't work, because it tries taking the ID of element 6 which is 6 but it tries to delete the item at index 6 instead of ID 6)

Please help me remove them based on their ID and not index but I want it with PLAIN javascript, not jQuery, thank you.

```
ul.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.id);
    if (event.target.className === "buttonClass"){
        for (let z = 0; z < ul.children.length; z++){
            let eh = event.target.parentNode.id;
            ul.children.getAttribute("id")[eh].remove()
        }
    }
}
```

While i think this code is enough, I will add all of it below it

```
let ul = document.querySelector("ul")
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");  
let selectInput = document.querySelector("input");

let createLi = function(){


    let createLi = document.createElement("li");
    let addNow = ul.appendChild(createLi);
    addNow.textContent = selectInput.value;
    selectInput.value = "";
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let createButton = addNow.appendChild(btn);
    createButton.textContent = "Button";
    createButton.setAttribute("class", "buttonClass");

   for(let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++){
       addNow.setAttribute("id", i)  
   }
};
```

HTML BELOW

```
<button id="main" onclick="createLi()"> add</button>
<input type="text" class="input">
<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your li element by its ID and remove it or Just use remove to the parent element which is the same li tag:

```
ul.addEventListener("click", function(event){

    let id = event.target.parentNode.id;
    document.getElementById(id).remove();

    // Or directly

    event.target.parentNode.remove();

});
```

Here is an example:

```js
let ul = document.querySelector("ul")
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");  
let selectInput = document.querySelector("input");

let createLi = function() {


    let createLi = document.createElement("li");
    let addNow = ul.appendChild(createLi);
    addNow.textContent = selectInput.value;
    selectInput.value = "";
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let createButton = addNow.appendChild(btn);
    createButton.textContent = "Button";
    createButton.setAttribute("class", "buttonClass");

   for(let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++){
       addNow.setAttribute("id", i);
   }
};


ul.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.id);
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
});
```

```html
<button id="main" onclick="createLi()"> add</button>
<input type="text" class="input">
<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is not needed to remove element:

```html
<u onclick=this.parentNode.removeChild(this)> Click to remove </u>
```

or [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to get the element that as clicked:

```html
<ul onclick=event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target)>
  <li> Item 1 </li>
  <li> Item 2 </li>
  <li> Item 3 </li>
  <li> Item 4 </li>
</ul>
```

---

Bonus: It can even be faked with CSS (but JavaScript is still needed to add nodes) :

```html
<style>[type], :checked + * { display: none }</style>
<input id=i><button onclick="i.value&&body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type=
checkbox id=${n=Date.now()}><label for=${n}>${i.value}<br></label>`)">Add</button><br>

<input type=checkbox id=1><label for=1> Item 1 <br></label>
<input type=checkbox id=2><label for=2> Item 2 <br></label>
<input type=checkbox id=3><label for=3> Item 3 <br></label>
<input type=checkbox id=4><label for=4> Item 4 <br></label>
```